# iPhone, "More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail." Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

When I try to read an image from the photo library I get the error, "More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail." The image is not read.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Tested this in my current project, and I can confirm that at the 5th call to the image picker from the photo library I still get this same warning on iOS 5.1.1 but not anymore on iOS 6.0, so in the new iOS version it is fixed apparently. Even though I get the warning on iOS 5.1.1, the image will still be picked and given back to my picker delegate, so I think I'll live with it.

Answer (score 17):

I think you are not checking the source type. 
You might be doing

```
 self.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

If this is the case, then you have to check the source type before assigning it directly.
like

```
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) 
  {
       // Set source to the Photo Library
       self.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

  }
```

I hope it helps

Comment: noticed this issue when opening the image picker for the second time and the code above solved my issue

Comment: On iOS 5.1.1, I do check for the availablity of the source type and still get the warning when I call the image picker for the 5th time. I do not see this on iOS 6.0 so Apple seems to have fixed something.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of this

```
self.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

Use

```
self.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
```

Comment: also check source type:   
if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]){
...
}

Comment: That is not a real fix for people like me who want to give access to the complete photo library.

Answer (score 2):

This worked it out for me:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    picker = nil;
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
}
```

I just set "picker = nil;" after dismissing the ModalViewController and then it works perfect :)

Hope it's going to help you out too :)

Comment: I also did set picker to nil but still I keep getting the warning when I call the image picker for the 5th time on iOS 5.1.1. On iOS 6.0 it seems to be fixed by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

The consensus [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689119/ios-5-gm-error-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689119/ios-5-gm-error-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register)) is that this is Apple's bug as even their own examples run into it. A radar has been filed against it.

Answer (score 0):

This is happen when allocating and presenting the UIImagePickerController more than 5 times.... I guess that the IOS forgets to de-register something when releasing/dismissing the UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 0):

For help follow link : http://skhousee.blogspot.in/2012/06/error-more-than-max-5-filtered-album.html

UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

ipc.delegate = self;

ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];

[ipc release];

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

```
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self setModalInPopover:YES];
```

}

Answer (score -5):

The answer was the issue only showed itself in iOS 5 Beta 6. After updating to beta 7 the issue is now gone.

Comment: I encounter this problem, under xCode 4.2 (4C199), released at Oct/12/2011, which include iOS SDK 5 (not beta). Well, I found another post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689119/ios-5-gm-error-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register

Comment: Yeah, I just got this in the long-released iOS 5 too.

Comment: I removed my accepted answer check as ya'll are right. In the released iOS 5, I am still having the same issue.

Comment: This issue is still there in the latest (as of 6/20/12) version of iOS 5.1.