# iOS 5 GM: <Error>: More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I know this thread [existed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167373/iphone-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register-this-will), but was closed as only appearing in iOS5 beta 6.
By now I have the Golden Master of iOS 5 on my phone and that error still appears.

This is happening when I create a `UIImagePickerController` with a `sourceType` of `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` more than 5 times. I am, as far as I can tell, creating and releasing the previous UIImagePickerController correctly each time.

Edit: adding code, as requested.

```
UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
ipc.delegate = self;
ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
[ipc release];
```

Later, I call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` when `-imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` gets called.

Comment: IOS 5 is still not released (as of 10/7/2011) and under NDA, so you're probably better off asking on Apple's developer forums...

Comment: Also, this sounds like something that might be the subject for a bug report, if you believe your usage of UIImagePickerController is correct: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: iOS 5 is out now, and I have this problem. Answers pls!

Comment: Post some code, post the link to the previous discussed thread and we could talk.

Comment: @OlegDanu previous thread is dull as ditchwater: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167373/iphone-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register-this-will basically just said "this only happens in beta 6, use beta 7".

Comment: I was the one that made the original thread. I was wrong in my answer stating it was only the beta. While it went away for me, it is back in the release version of 5.0.1. I do not have a fix for it and would be interested if you happen to come across it. It is like you say, after about five image picker calls it comes up but to my knowledge, I'm doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem happens in Apple examples, so the best bet is to ignore.

Comment: Filed bug report, rdar://10306359

Answer (score 0):

> Later, I call [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; when
>   -imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo: gets called.

Have you tried to set the delegate of the image picker to nil, in **didFinishPickingImage** ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not your fault.It may be vary in different version.Apple should solve this issue.Main thing is that you should check for memory leak is important.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this [UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7251451/600076)

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
picker=nil
```

in the

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
picker = nil;
}
```

it works for me......

Comment: I don't want to sound rude or anything but setting 'picker' to null in that context will do absolutely nothing. All it will do is mark the variable in that context to nil. It won't release any memory (as it is held by the caller of that method I'm guessing). The fact that it 'works' for you could be based on other factors, I'm guessing.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one, i am sure this is gonna help you;

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self setModalInPopover:YES];
}
```