# After calling UIImagePickerController multiple times the device restarts

Tags: iphone, crash, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, restart

I implement UIImagePickerController delegate, UINavigationController delegate, UIPopOverController delegate. I have no clue what the problem is. My device restarts after calling this 3, 4 or 5 times ( It is different each build ). Please help me fix it!!

EDIT: I get this error:

```
More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail.
```

Here is the code I am using to call UIImagePickerController and get the image:

```
- (IBAction)imgPickerPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        imgPickerTypeActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose image source:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Photo Library", nil];
        [imgPickerTypeActionSheet showInView:self];
    }
    else {
        UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [controller setDelegate:self];
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
            [controller setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        }
        imgPickerPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
        imgPickerPopOver.delegate = self;
        [imgPickerPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(imgPickerButton.frame.origin.x, imgPickerButton.frame.origin.x-250, 0.0, 0.0) 
                                          inView:self
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown 
                                        animated:YES];
    }
}
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([actionSheet isEqual:imgPickerTypeActionSheet]) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
            UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            [controller setDelegate:self];
            [controller setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

            [[delegate getVC] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            [controller setDelegate:self];
            [controller setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

            imgPickerPopOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
            imgPickerPopOver.delegate = self;
            [imgPickerPopOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(imgPickerButton.frame.origin.x, imgPickerButton.frame.origin.x-250, 1, 1) 
                                              inView:self
                            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown 
                                            animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    [imgPickerPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    pickedImageView.image = image;
    [self valueChanged:nil];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by device restart? i mean it switch off and switch on automatically

Comment: The device reboots. The actual device restarts, the device turns off and turns back on

Comment: I found an error but do not know a fix

Comment: More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail.

Comment: you did not mention for which device you are running, i mean iPhone 3G, 4G, 4Gs blah blah

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167373/iphone-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register-this-will

Comment: i've seen that before and followed it but id din't fix it, but thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in the iOS simulator? Also are you releasing any of these objects, or is ARC doing it?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167373/iphone-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register-this-will) may help.

Comment: ARC is doing it and yes it is fine in the simulator