# Xcode Error With More Than 5 UIImages

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone, “More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail.” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167373/iphone-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register-this-will)

When I'm adding images to UIImageViews via Popover Controller or Modal View Controller, after the 4th image, when I go to add the 5th, Xcode's debugger outputs: **"Error: More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail.**" It will still let me add in 5+ pictures, but only 4 of them save. I've done some research on here about this, and found this question:
[iOS 5 GM: <Error>: More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689119/ios-5-gm-error-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register)

The answer in here appears as though it is a bug with Apple, and that it should be ignored. Well, Apple is usually (somewhat) quick about fixing their Xcode bugs, and this has been around for a while, so I'm starting to wonder what the real cause is. I think this error is related to my app only saving up to 4 of the pictures.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
- (IBAction)grabImage {
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
        [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.imageView.bounds inView:self.imageView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    } 

    else {
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
    }
    [self.imgPicker resignFirstResponder];
}
// Sets the image in the UIImageView
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
    if (imageView.image == nil) {
        imageView.image = img;

        [self.array addObject:imageView];

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;

    }

    if (imageView2.image == nil) {
        imageView2.image = img;
        NSLog(@"The image is a %@", imageView);
        [self.array addObject:imageView2];

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }

    if (imageView3.image == nil) {
        imageView3.image = img;

        [self.array addObject:imageView3];

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }

    if (imageView4.image == nil) {
        imageView4.image = img;

        [self.array addObject:imageView4];

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }
    if (imageView5.image == nil) {
        imageView5.image = img;

        [self.array addObject:imageView5];

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Here is my current code:

```
- (IBAction)grabImage {
    if (self.imgPicker == nil) {
        self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    }

    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
        [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.imageView.bounds inView:self.imageView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    } 

    else {
        [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
    }
    [self.imgPicker resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Yes, an exact duplicate. We should reopen the original, though.

Comment: @IuliusCæsar I did. More votes are needed.

Comment: @Costique: Oh, damn, I thought that was my vote, but it expired already. Well, it'll pop up in the 10K tools' reopen list again. A mod flag is always an option if necessary.

Comment: Really, voted to close this? The "duplicate" is not helpful at all, this one was already providing more info than the other ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the other questions linked, it sounds like this is an Apple bug, but related to creating multiple `UIImagePickerController`s. You're only presenting one image picker controller at a time, so maybe you should create one the first time you call your `grabImage` and then reuse it instead of creating a new one each time.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense, thank you. I'm extremely new to programming, do you know how I would edit my code to do that?

Comment: You're putting a new instance of `UIImagePickerController` into the property `self.imgPicker`. Before the first time this happens, that property's value will be `nil`. Afterward, it'll be the image picker controller. What do you think you should check for and when? (Hint: this follows the same pattern as when you're conditionally setting an image view's image.)

Comment: Cool thanks a lot, that makes sense. I think that I would need to check to see if the image picker controller is nil, in my imagePickerController method's if statements?

Comment: Yup. Check to see that it's nil before creating it.

Comment: Great thank you. I'm still new to the code, so I'm not sure how it should look. I was thinking about putting `if (imgPicker == nil)` under each of my if statements, like this: `if (imageView.image == nil) if (imgPicker == nil) {...}.` Would that be correct?

Comment: You only need to worry about whether your image picker exists already when you create it -- that is, on one line. `if (self.imgPicker == nil) self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];`

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated my code using that, but the issue is still occurring. I updated my OP at the bottom with the code I'm currently using. I'm pretty sure I did it right but may not have.

Comment: I get this issue all the time, I only ever create one UIImagePickerController. Seems like a bug that happens when debugging...