# Get image from photo library for multiple times shows error

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

In my iPhone app , when I use UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary as the source type, after opening it for 5 times , I get :

```
<Error>: More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail.
```

in my console.And also the image picked is gone.

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]==YES) {

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;    
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release]; 
}
```

And in method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

I dismiss the modalviewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to creating multiple UIImagePickerControllers. You're only presenting one image picker controller at a time, so maybe you should create one the first time you call your grabImage and then reuse it instead of creating a new one each time.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159056/xcode-error-with-more-than-5-uiimages) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167373/iphone-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register-this-will) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689119/ios-5-gm-error-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register) links

Comment: I have it initialized in viewDidLoad method and it is allocated only once and released in dealloc method

Comment: i think its better to ignore it