# "More than maximum 5 filtered albums trying to register. This will fail." using AssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, assetslibrary

I sometimes get "More than maximum 5 filtered albums trying to register. This will fail." when I call setAssetsFilter on a ALAssetsGroup.

Anyone knows why? I've seen similar questions but all related to the UIImagePickerController.

here the code:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [lib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {....}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most guys on this have seen this question:[iOS 5 GM: : More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689119/ios-5-gm-error-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register). And this: [iPhone, “More than maximum 5 filtered album lists trying to register. This will fail.” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167373/iphone-more-than-maximum-5-filtered-album-lists-trying-to-register-this-will). So we can believe that this is a known issue bug. No big problem.

I also see this comment:

> On iOS 5.1.1, I do check for the availablity of the source type and
>   still get the warning when I call the image picker for the 5th time. I
>   do not see this on iOS 6.0 so Apple seems to have fixed something. –
>   [Richard Altenburg - Brainchild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690497/richard-altenburg-brainchild)

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is an Apple Bug!..Even Apple examples give the same Error. Better to ignore it!

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this issue, but got it fixed. you just need to change the source type of UIImagePickerController.

UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

/* This works fine in IOS6 but has some problem in IOS5 */
// imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum; // This would Solve the problem.